# gitlab's invalid two-factor code

Tags: gitlab, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have set 2FA on my gitlab account, and then deleted the google authenticator app on my phone. 
When I tried to login again, the recovery code that I've inserted didn't work, and so I downloaded the google authenticator app again, but the code in the authenticator app does not work when I try to sign in (I get "invalid two-factor code").
Changing my password didn't work :( 
Any help?

Comment: also tried "ssh <my_gitlab_username> 2fa_recovery_codes", didn't help

Comment: well the command actually should be:
ssh git@gitlab.com 2fa_recovery_codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your recovery code doesn't work, contact to Gitlab administrators. They will disable two-factor authentication for your account. For the future, you should better save QR code and keep it in a safe place. Then, if you lose your phone or delete Google Authenticator, you could easily restore it.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually wasn't aware that they had this option.
This is where you should contact hem from:
https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: What if you are the gitlab administrator with root-access?